# Pybats forecast error when using Poisson family distribution

Tags: python, time-series, poisson

I am building a timeseries PyBats model using a Poisson distribution to signify the distribution of observations. My model instantiation looks like this

```
 model = define_dglm(
        Y=data.actual.values,
        X=None,
        family="poisson",
        k=1,
        prior_length=8,
        dates=data["month"],
        ntrend=2,
        seasPeriods=[],
        seasHarmComponents=[],
        nsamps=10000,
    )
```

Where `data.actual.values` is a numpy array of integers. After instantiating the model, in order to forecast into the future with pybats I run

```
forecast_samples = model.forecast_path(k=steps_to_forecast, X=X_future, nsamps=10000)
```

and get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybats/dglm.py", line 289, in forecast_path
    return forecast_path_copula(self, k, X, nsamps, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybats/forecast.py", line 211, in forecast_path_copula
    return forecast_path_copula_sim(mod, k, lambda_mu, lambda_cov, nsamps, t_dist, nu)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybats/forecast.py", line 326, in forecast_path_copula_sim
    return np.array(list(map(lambda prior: mod.simulate_from_sampling_model(prior, nsamps),
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybats/forecast.py", line 326, in <lambda>
    return np.array(list(map(lambda prior: mod.simulate_from_sampling_model(prior, nsamps),
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybats/dglm.py", line 477, in simulate_from_sampling_model
    return np.random.poisson(rate, [nsamps])
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 3573, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.poisson
  File "_common.pyx", line 824, in numpy.random._common.disc
  File "_common.pyx", line 621, in numpy.random._common.discrete_broadcast_d
  File "_common.pyx", line 355, in numpy.random._common.check_array_constraint
ValueError: lam value too large
```

I have tried converting my `Y` array to floats, and have tried replacing all 0 values with 1 and get the same error. What is causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in exceeding the maximum value allowed in `numpy.random.poisson`. It looks like any value larger than `np.random.poisson(1E19)` will cause this error.

A couple things you can try:

- Use a longer prior length than 8 when defining the model. This will help produce more stable estimates of the coefficients. After defining your model, check what the coefficient mean vector (`model.a`) and covariance matrix (`model.R`) are, to make sure they're reasonable. If they're not, you can change them manually.
- If some of your 'Y' values are truly that large, a Poisson model is probably not appropriate. I would suggest modeling log(Y) using the normal `dlm` model in Pybats.

I hope that this help!

Thanks,
Isaac